# Rails Comments User + Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, comments

In my Rails app, I have a comments scaffold which lets users comment on a movie.

I am faced with two problems.

The first problem is that anyone can create a comment, even if they are not signed in, how would I assign a comment to a user, so if there is a `current_user`, they can create a comment and I would be able to assign the user to the comment so <%= comment.user.first_name %>, and if they are not signed in, they cant create a comment. How would i do this? ( I am using devise )

The second problem is that when I create a comment, it takes me to this path (where 12 is :movie_id)

```
localhost:3000/movies/12/comments/new
```

This is fine but when i am creating the comment, I have to specify the movie_id (12), how this be done automatically, so rails sees that the movie_id for the comment is 12.

**My Comments Controller, incase needed**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  before_filter :load_movie


  def index
    @comments = @movie.comments.all
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.json
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /comments/1
  # PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        format.html { redirect_to (@movie), notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    def load_movie
      @movie = Movie.find_by_id(:movie_id)
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
using devise, you can request that a user is signed in by saying at the top of your controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create]
```

so if someone not signed in tries to access these actions, they are redirected to the sign in page and after sign in forwarded to the original request.

Second:
As you can see from the routes, 12 is assigned to params[:movie_id]. So in your controllers `new` action write:

```
@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
@comment = @movie.comments.new
@comment.user=current_user
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks everything works perfectly, except for the       <%= comment.user.first_name %>  I get undefined method `first_name'

Comment: well, add the user to comment (I extended my answer)

Comment: I still get the error =>>   undefined method `first_name'   <<=      When using <%= comment.user.first_name %>

Comment: the error is `undefined method 'first_name' for <some_object>`. What is the object shown?